# Back to Top button sliding from bottom right hand side corner of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to integrate a custom back to top button on a web page, but I can't move (slide) it with JQuery. What I want is to slide the button from the invisible part of the screen right to left when page scroll reaches a particular amount, and slide it from left to right (to the invisible part of the screen) when scroll amount is less than the specified.

Any advice or a fragment of code would be of great value!

Here is the code:

custom css:

```css
a.custom-back-to-top {
 width: 80px;
 height: 40px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: bold;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;
 right: -100px;
 bottom: 20px;
 background: #444;
}
```

and this is the jquery

```js
$('body').append('<a href="#" class="custom-back-to-top">Back to Top</a>');

var scrollAmount = 1000;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollAmount)
    {
        $('a.custom-back-to-top').animate({'right':'20px'}, 'slow');
    }
    else
    {
        $('a.custom-back-to-top').animate({'right':'-100px'}, 'slow');
    }
});

$('a.custom-back-to-top').click(function() {
  
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Show us what have you done so far, and if you have one, what errors you have

Comment: Your script is working, but for some strange reason, the jQuery `.animate()` function in the `if` blocks takes too long to execute, setting a very minimal `duration` you can see it working [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/o3gnogtv/3/)

Comment: OK, Cliff, thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, it's working. However, it's not moving as smooth as "fadein" or "fadeout". Could we make it move smoother somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var button_threshold = someNumber;

    if ($(window). scrollTop > button_threshold) {
        // Move button into view
    } else {
        // Move button out of view
    }
});
```

Comment: Carter, the "move button into and out of view" part of the code is the one which I am looking solution for ;-)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.